# A tool to browse/extract data from the Google App Engine Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking for tool (data extract utility) to browse/extract data from the Google App Engine Datastore. I found one but it hasn't been released - [GAEBrowser](http://theludditegeek.com/gaebrowser/). Does anybody know of a similar tool? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I know one, of course, the datastore viewer in GAE admin console: https://appengine.google.com/datastore/explorer?&app_id={yourappid}

What's wrong with the official datastore viewer anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You might also look into remote_api, which lets you write Python scripts that run on your own computer but access your app's Datastore: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api